# Should I pull from dev branch before pushing a new feature branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, workflow

Git workflow for a feature branch: 
dev branch has files: 1.txt and package.json 
I branch from dev to do featureX

```
git branch -b featureX
```

I work on featureX branch and add X.txt 
Now before I push dev branch already has 1.txt, 2.txt and package.json  
Do I need to checkout on dev branch and pull before I push so that I have the 2.txt file? 
Or pull from my current branch or I just push?

```
git checkout dev
git pull origin dev
git checkout featureX
git pull from dev to featureX (i don't even know what this command looks like)
git add .
git commit -m "added feature X"
git push origin featureX
```

or

```
git pull origin featureX
git add .
git commit -m "added feature X"
git push origin featureX
```

or just

```
git add .
git commit -m "added feature X"
git push origin featureX
```

Or the pull before a push is needed only when I add some code in file package.json for example and someone else also added something there.
I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which interface you would prefer to handle merge conflicts.

Personally I like to handle merge conflicts locally so would pull first.

You say you are adding X.txt and the updated remote already has 1.txt and 2.txt. Taken literally there will be no merge conflicts.

If you're asking which of your blocks of instructions I would use I would highlight the absence of any specific `git add`.

Comment: So basically i don't need the 2.txt in my featureX branch to do a clean push without merge conflict. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "clean push". But git is smart enought to not delete it in the remote just because the commit you are pushing doesn't _yet_ have it. Were you to have it already and then delete it, that would be a different matter.

Comment: Thank's a lot John that's answering my doubts.